# How to exclude certain combination pattern in data set?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set where I have to get rid off the student if he/she has the grade other than "F". here in an example, Brian has grades other than "F", so, Brian should not appear in my result. Only Jack should appear, as, I want EXCLUSIVELY "F" grade students.

I tried it in SQL using NOT IN, EXCEPT functions, but I am not able to resolve the issue (Please click to see the screen shot).

[image: CODE Example]

As mentioned above, I am only expecting jack's record, as Brian has grades other than "F". I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us what you have tried

Comment: Sorry for a confusion. I am using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want `'Jack'`, then you can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(grade) = max(grade) and min(grade) = 'F';
```

If you actually want the original rows, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.grade <> 'F');
```